# EWS Appointment server change timestamp

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm working on buffer solution for MS Exchange server.
The buffer should store events and keep them in sync with Exchange server.
I code in C# and use Managed EWS.

The buffer queries Exchange for appointments changed in sequential intervals:

(t[1], t[2]), (t[2], t[3]), (t[3], t[4])
...

I use **Appointment.LastModifiedTime** field to filter out appointments changed in interval (t[x], t[x+1]). However I discovered, that this field takes it value from *time of modification on client*. What I need is some *timestamp of modification on server*.

Imagine the case: user X goes offline and adds appointment on t[Y] in his Outlook client. On t[Z] = t[Y] + 24h user X goes online. His Outlook client will sync with Exchange server and this new appoinment appears on it with LastModifiedDate = t[Y]. Is there some field to get t[Z] ?

For now I see full sync as a 100% working alternative to this, but it is a 'hammer solution' with obvious drawbacks. I will have to use it in case nobody can give an alternative :)